# Nested foreach %dopar% in R

Tags: r, foreach

So i have successfully used foreach %dopar% in R with one loop (say "i"). Right now I'm trying foreach with two loops (say "i" and "j").

I need to run correlation analysis between two large dataframes. DF1 has 22 features and 280 samples (the value "i" loops through the rows of this DF). DF2 has about 20,000 features and the same 280 samples (the value "j" loops through the rows of this DF)

From my debugging, what I have understood is that this code I wrote only runs for the loops where i and j have the same value. i,e, for 1 and j = 1, 2,....22.

The loop is not running for the other j values. Could someone help me figure out how to edit the code to make it work for all "i" and "j" values ? Thank you very much !

My code is below.

```
corrResult1<-foreach(i=1:nrow(DF1),j=1:nrow(DF2),.combine=rbind) %dopar% {
oneValueDF1 = as.numeric(DF1[i,])
oneValueDF2 = as.numeric(DF2[j,])
myCor1 = cor(x = oneValueDF1, y = oneValueDF2 , method = "pearson")
    #correlation test
myCor1_test = cor.test(oneValueDF2, oneValueDF1, method="pearson") 

tempMatrix = cbind(oneValueDF1, oneValueDF2,
                       myCor1_test$statistic, # T stat
                       myCor1_test$parameter, #DF
                       myCor1_test$p.value, #p alue
                       myCor1_test$estimate, #corr coeff
                       myCor1_test$conf.int[1], #conf int 1
                       myCor1_test$conf.int[2], #conf int 2
                       myCor1_test$null.value, 
                       myCor1_test$alternative,
                       myCor1_test$method) 

    tempMatrix
```

}

Comment: I'm trying this out now. Lets see if it works: corrResult1<-foreach(i=1:nrow(DF1),.combine=rbind) %:% 
    foreach(j=1:nrow(DF2),.combine=rbind) %dopar% { ..... }

Answer (score 0):

This works. In case its helpful for anyone:

```
corrResult1<-foreach(i=1:nrow(DF1),.combine=rbind) %:% 
             foreach(j=1:nrow(DF2),.combine=rbind) %dopar% { 

oneValueDF1 = as.numeric(DF1[i,])
oneValueDF2 = as.numeric(DF2[j,])
myCor1 = cor(x = oneValueDF1, y = oneValueDF2 , method = "pearson")
#correlation test
myCor1_test = cor.test(oneValueDF2, oneValueDF1, method="pearson") 

tempMatrix = cbind(oneValueDF1, oneValueDF2,
                   myCor1_test$statistic, # T stat
                   myCor1_test$parameter, #DF
                   myCor1_test$p.value, #p alue
                   myCor1_test$estimate, #corr coeff
                   myCor1_test$conf.int[1], #conf int 1
                   myCor1_test$conf.int[2], #conf int 2
                   myCor1_test$null.value, 
                   myCor1_test$alternative,
                   myCor1_test$method) 

    tempMatrix 

         }
```